# connecting nodes from Neo4j with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, graph-databases

I have imported CSV file in Neo4j database. Part of code looks like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from "file:///AccountTry.csv" as row
WITH row, split(row.birth_date, '-') as date
CREATE (a:AccountTest {id: toInteger(row.id), account_type: row.account_type, first_name: row.first_name, last_name: row.last_name })
```

and that works fine. I can see all my nodes and their attributes in neo4j browser.
Then, i created model in rails application:

```
class AccountTest
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :first_name, type: String
  property :id, type: Integer
  property :last_name, type: String
  property :account_type, type: String
end
```

I made migration and that works fine. When i open rails console and try "AccountTest.first" i get all atributes fine, only property "AccountTest.id: nil".

Why is "id" nil? I have 6 nodes and all of them in rails application have id = nil, but in Neo4j browser all of them have correct ids.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to declare the id property in the AccountTest class. This property is the primary key and is there by default.

As this is an additional property (different form the id generated by Neo4j) I suggest that you rename the property on AccountTest (e.g. account_id) and change the CSV import to load the value into the account_id field.

Comment: In Neo4j database i have two "id"s:

<id> - witch is made by neo4j,    
id - from relational database that i got from importing CSV file (i need that one)